# How to mock AWS Amplify library in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, mocking, aws-amplify

I am getting an error that seems to come from AWS Amplify when I run the suite of tests with Karma.

```js
AuthEffects
    login
      √ should not dispatch any action
      √ should call setItem on LocalStorageService
Chrome 78.0.3904 (Windows 10.0.0) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientMetadata' of undefined thrown
```

From that I suppose that this error is thrown from the last test that was launched: AuthEffects

In my AuthEffects, I had to do that to make AWS amplify working

```js
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
//...

const promise = Auth.signIn(username, password);
```

I don't understand how I can mock this API access to the Cognito. 
Usually, I provide a Mock service to the constructor by dependendies injection to avoid real connection to the API. Here it's directly imported in the component.

Spec file:

```js
describe('login', () => {
    it('should not dispatch any action', () => {
      const actions = new Actions(EMPTY);
      const effect = new AuthEffects(
      //...
      );
      const metadata = getEffectsMetadata(effect);

      expect(metadata.login).toEqual({ dispatch: false });
    });

    it('should call setItem on LocalStorageService', () => {
      const loginAction = new ActionAuthLogin('test', 'Test1234!');
      const source = cold('a', { a: loginAction });
      const actions = new Actions(source);
      const effect = new AuthEffects(
      //...
      );

      effect.login.subscribe(() => {
        expect(localStorageService.setItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith(AUTH_KEY, {
          isAuthenticated: true
        });
      });
    });

    afterAll(() => {
      TestBed.resetTestingModule();
    });
  });
```

Is there a way to override this import from the spec file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it like this:

```
// service with Auth
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import Auth, { CognitoUser } from '@aws-amplify/auth';
...

private getProfile(): void {
   return from(Auth.currentUserInfo());
}


// service.spec.ts
it('should set user and user profile', async () => {
   const userProfile = { profile: 'userProfile' } as any;
    
   Auth.currentUserInfo = jasmine.createSpy().and.callFake(() => Promise.resolve(userProfile));
       
   const resp = await service.getProfile.toPromise();
   expect(resp).toEqual(userProfile)
      
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get rid of the error.

You need to import Auth in the test file and the types that will be needed in the following solution.

```js
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
import { ClientMetaData, SignInOpts } from '@aws-amplify/auth/src/types/Auth';
```

Now, redefining the signIn method of the Auth will solve the problem:

```js
describe('AuthEffects', () => {
//...
Auth.signIn = (
    usernameOrSignInOpts: string | SignInOpts,
    pw?: string,
    clientMetadata: ClientMetaData = this._config.clientMetadata
  ) => of({}).toPromise();
//...
```

You need to follow the signature of the method to override it.

```js
public signIn(
        usernameOrSignInOpts: string | SignInOpts,
        pw?: string,
        clientMetadata: ClientMetaData = this._config.clientMetadata
    ): Promise<CognitoUser | any>
```

I don't know if it's the best (cleaner) solution to perform it, but I manage to get rid of the error and control the behavior of the Auth instance.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than import it directly into your service or Effects class, import it into your Module and inject it. Assuming you have an `AuthService` service class handling AWS Amplify's Auth.

In your corresponding module:

```
import Auth, { AuthClass } from '@aws-amplify/auth';
...
providers: [
    AuthService,
    { provide: AuthClass, useValue: Auth }
  ]
```

In your component or service, simply inject it like any other dependency:

```
constructor(
    private auth: AuthClass
    ) {
       auth.signIn('abc', 'def')
    }
```

And finally, in your spec file you mock it and use a Spy:

```
describe('AuthService', () => {
  let service: AuthService;
  let authSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<AuthClass>
  let authSpyObj = {
    signIn: () => new Promise<any>(() => true),
    signOut: () => new Promise<any>(() => true),
    signUp: () => new Promise<any>(() => true),
    confirmSignUp: () => new Promise<any>(() => true),
    resendSignUp: () => new Promise<any>(() => true),
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    const spyAuth = jasmine.createSpyObj('auth', authSpyObj);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        AuthService,
        { provide: AuthClass, useValue: spyAuth },
      ]
    })

    service = TestBed.inject(AuthService)
    authSpy = TestBed.inject(AuthClass) as jasmine.SpyObj<AuthClass>    
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should have called signIn', () => {
    service.signIn('a@b.c', '12345678')
    expect(authSpy.signIn).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
});
```

This test file doesn't do much right now except confirm that your service/component is calling the expect Auth functions, but this should get you off the ground. Enjoy.