# How to mock AWS amplify methods in Angular unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I am using [AWS cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/), [Amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/) and [Angular 10](https://angular.io/).

I want a navbar not to be rendered if a user is not logged in:

app.html:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isLoggedIn">
  <navbar></navbar>
</ng-container>
```

app.ts:

```
constructor() {
  this.checkIfLoggedIn();
}

checkIfLoggedIn() {
  Auth.currentUserInfo().then((userData) => {
    if (userData) {
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
    }
  });
}
```

This works. However, my unit tests ([Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/latest/index.html)/[Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/)) throw an error:

```
Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly.
        The configuration object is missing required auth properties.
```

This is because I don't know hot to mock `Auth.currentUserInfo.then` correctly (despite reading various posts about it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59215244/how-to-mock-aws-amplify-library-in-angular) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60454057/how-do-i-properly-mock-amplify-for-unit-testing-in-jasmine)).

Attempts:

**1) SpyOn**

I thought it would be something like `spyOn(Auth, 'currentUserInfo').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));`

**2) Mocking `Auth` in providers**

like suggested in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65250583/how-to-mock-aws-amplify-methods-in-angular-unit-testing?noredirect=1#comment115356708_65250583).

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

beforeEach(async () => {
  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [
      {
        provide: Auth,
        useValue: { currentUserInfo: () => Promise.resolve('hello') },
      },
    ],
  }).compileComponents();
}
```

Unfortunately they don't make the error message go away.

Comment: Auth is initialized even though you spied on it. Try in providers `{provide: Auth, useValue: { currentUserInfo: () => Promise.resolve(true) }}`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I appreciate it. Unfortunately this did not work, I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried with `useClass: MyClass` instead of useValue?

Comment: Yes. That gives an "unreachable" error, like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62281756/jasmine-angular-9-test-failing-because-unreachable-stack-trace-at-injectablede

Comment: Ok, used it wrong. If I mock a service (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62284218/3255061), there is no "unreachable", but there is still the "Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly.
        The configuration object is missing required auth properties." error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `Auth` is a global object.
Therefore the way with `spyOn(Auth, 'currentUserInfo').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));` is the right one, but it should be called before `TestBed.configureTestingModule`.

```js
const backup: any;

// faking currentUserInfo
beforeEach(() => {
  backup = Auth.currentUserInfo;
  Auth.currentUserInfo = jasmine.createSpy()
    .and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));
});

// restoring original function
afterEach(() => {
  Auth.currentUserInfo = backup;
});

// now our test begins
beforeEach(async () => {
  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
  }).compileComponents();
});
```